# Replace domain in database

Tags: security, hacked

My site is attacked, so basically all the core php files are corrupted and broken. Only the database is left.

Now I tried in my localhost.

1. If I want to restore my site from this database, is domain name the
   only thing that I need to replace string?
2. I've found this tutorial - [Replace string in database](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A3=ind1208&L=MOODLE-UK&E=quoted-printable&P=1387714&B=--_000_9979A53BDA5D2741B3EE070FF8C3876C02C098EADB3PRD0410MB369_&T=text%2Fhtml;%20charset=iso-8859-1&pending=) - to
   change the domain strings in all tables, but hardly know where to
   put it in and how to trigger it in wordpress.

Comment: Hi. Your database can be corrupted too. Some scripts can detect WordPress installations and attack the database using WP credentials. Doesn't your hosting provide a backup/restore?

Comment: @JackJohansson the database is what I can try now. I'm not sure but it seems like they don't provide it so they ask me to fix it.

Comment: If you downloaded the database from your website, then the URLs are correct. Why do you need to change them?

Comment: I'd rather try with my localhost first before changing anything.

Comment: Well, then you can try [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin to replace all `localhost` strings with your domain. Upload the database, change `siteurl` and `homeurl` in the cpanel, and then use the plugin (make sure you don't replace `localhost` with `http://http://localhost/` or something). Tada.

Comment: Hang on, if you have a working local copy why don't you upload that? Since the db copy you downloaded from the server might be infected you should actually only use the local copy db. Use [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to make a copy of the local site with working db and then upload.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the Better Search and Replace plugin is great for search/replace of the WP database.

But be aware that there are many other things you need to do to recover a hacked site. There are many places to get that info, but when I do it, I

- change all credentials/passwords: database, FTP, hosting, admin-level
  users
- reinstall WP (from the Updates screen), then reinstall all
  plugins/themes from original sources
- Look closely at all files for modified dates that are not 'right'
  (using the hosting/FTP file manager to sort by date is helpful; most 
  valid files will have similar dates)
- Remove access to the xmlrpc.prg fle - that is a great attack vector
- Check for any file names that are not expected. And check everywhere.

Details on how I recover from a hacked site are more than can be placed in an answer here. But I've detailed my procedure [here](https://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/), which may be helpful. It is possible to recover a hacked site, but it does take some effort. And it will take a while for the search engines to get the changes updated after you fix things.